# jquery: Changing input label's color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<label>       
<input type="radio" id="other" name="level_0" value="other" class="other">other
</label>
```

Say I have the above in an unordered list. On clicking the radio button, I want the label to be colored red.

I have tried the following:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).prev().css("color","red");
}
});
```

Shouldn't this grab the previous element, 'label', and change its color to red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest('label').addClass("red");
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="level_0" value="other" class="other">other
</label>
```

1. Use `.closest()`
2. `.prev()` is used for siblings element.
3. Can also use `.parent()`
4. Suggestion use `.addClass()` instead of adding style directly

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the prev() query searches too far back. When I changed it to parent() (which makes sense, because input is within label), it worked correctly. This is what happens when you don't study the fundamentals of what you're doing!

Comment: `.prev() is used for siblings element.` it does not search too far back

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).closest('label').css({"color":"red"});
  }
});
```

change prev() in to closest() and bracket inside of parenthesis if you want to use css()

https://jsfiddle.net/darkrulerbreaker/neqrknkr/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jquery for this at all - have the CSS do it all. also - to be clear - are you after the label text - to be red (use color) or the label background to be red (use background). This will change the label color / background on the checked state of the input rather than the click event.

From the CSS tricks site (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/) - "The :checked pseudo-class selector matches radio and checkbox input types when checked or toggled to an on state. If they are not selected or checked, there is no match.".

Note that this affects the label AFTER the input.

```css
input[type=radio]:checked + label{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="option1" name="level_0" value="1" class="other">
  <label>option 1</label>       
<input type="radio" id="option2" name="level_0" value="2" class="other">
  <label>option 2</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I wanted to change the text red so I could practice moving around elements with jquery. I'll be using it to figure out how to get (and hide) parents siblings children. It will probably be the next question I post.